# php.log: what is the proper way to clear log file?

Tags: php, unix, logging

I'm troubleshooting a php log file that has expanded way too rapidly and used up a lot of disk space.

What is the best way to clear a log file?

is it a problem to simply delete the log file? And will that log file be recreated as php tries to write to it?

Comment: A simple way to test would be to rename the file and see if it gets re-created (which afaik, it should).

Comment: @tigrang, thank you for the response. but before i rename or remove, i'd like to know about safely emptying a log file, if there is such a way

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is entirely safe to just delete the php.log file. It will be auto-created the next time it is needed.

Comment: restart apache after
`service apache2 restart`

Comment: @mate.gwozdz there's no need to restart the server, besides, Apache doesn't handle the PHP log, that's handled by PHP

Comment: Before restarting apache the file was not created. Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 7):

On Linux you can do :

```
cat /dev/null > /var/logs/php.log
```

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X 10.6 I deleted **/var/log/apache2/error_log**.  Minor panic when it didn't re-appear upon refreshing my page.  Just had to restart apache by going through the Sharing settings.  Now she's back.

Comment: nginx, no need to restart server

Answer (score 0):

It **IS** safe to delete the log file by doing the following:

1. Delete the php.log file altogether.
2. If on Apache Restart the Server using "service apache2 restart" command
3. If on NGINX you do not have to restart the server

Answer (score 0):

You can run this simple command from terminal(in WHM) or From SSH terminal.

```
find -name error_log -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This command will find all files with name "error_log" and remove it.

Enjoy.